# Try playing AVPlayerItem again after it failed

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `AVPlayer` that loads a `URL` of an HLS livestream. The problem is that when I first receive the `URL` of the stream, the `URL` exists but the video at the `URL` doesn't. Only after around 10 seconds does the video then work (because of the delay in outputting an HLS stream).

I observe the status of my `AVPlayerItem` like this:

```
observationToken = player?.currentItem?.observe(\.status, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (item, change) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.spinner.stopAnimating()

            switch item.status {
            case .readyToPlay:
                print("PLAY THE STREAM")
                // Player item is ready to play.
                self?.player?.play()
            case .failed:
                print("FAILED", item.error)
                // Player item failed. See error.
                break
            case .unknown:
                print("THE PLAYER ISN'T REASDY YET")
                // Player item is not yet ready.
                break
            @unknown default:
                print("SOME OTHER THING")
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens is the status changes to `.failed` with the error message "HTTP 404: File Not Found". How can I make it retry when it hits a `.failed` status?

Comment: What if you observe the AVPlayer's `timeControlStatus`?

Comment: @matt Apple's docs say that's for network conditions though. This is a video on the web that goes from not existing to existing

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. — Apple has sample code and discussion here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams They seem to say that what you are describing is normal and the status will update again when the stream is ready.

Comment: The `AVPlayerItem` `status` never changes after it's gone to `failed`. I tried `isPlayable`, and that returns `true` when the status is `failed`, so that doesn't help :(

Comment: So the Apple sample example code doesn't work on your HLS stream? If that's the case, you should probably file a bug report.

Comment: It's not a bug that a URL that doesn't lead to anywhere returns failed. They're assuming you provide a URL to an HLS stream that already exists